# JQuery - Serialize cookie string value to object/array type

Tags: jquery, json, cookies

Im using jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js in retrieving cookie values:

```
$cookie = $.cookies.get('ci_session');
//generates a:5:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"46645fe9eb70e1b157f24b724932be24";s:10:"ip_address";s:9:"127.0.0.1";s:10:"user_agent";s:50:"Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+en-US;+rv";s:13:"last_activity";s:10:"1298530444";s:15:"promos_userinfo";a:1:{s:8:"username";s:9:"requester";}}c53a500fb3108c3930da58d50b6db036
```

my problem is how convert this string to object type or array type.
I have tried to parse it using JSON.parse() but there is an error. please help how to
use JSON.parse or any method that can parse the string.

Comment: Do you want a generic function turning this into a JavaScript object, or something specific to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a version of [PHP's `unserialize()` ported to JavaScript](http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize:571).

Comment: thank you for your response. but is there anyway to unserialize it in jquery.

Comment: @user575282 jQuery is a JavaScript framework. Unless you want to turn the code linked into a jQuery plugin, just use the function (maybe namespace it like so `util.unserialize = function() { ... }`).